# How to fix, images loaded in multi thread sometimes don't show up on the form

Tags: multithreading, image, delphi, firemonkey

In my manga viewer i try to load a large number of images (around 200), i try loading these images inside an `anonymous thread` and when the loading finishes i call a `Thread.synchronize`, this works fine, but in some cases i keep seeing some images not drawn on the form (I think they are loaded because i can see the information about the image), how can i solve this?

This issue only happens in `multi thread` so i decided to set the image visible to false and then at the end of the loading inside a `Thread.synchronize` turn the visible to true, i had hoped this would force some kind of refresh or redraw, but the problem i mentioned consists

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
  begin
      for imageIndex := 0 to fileList.count - 1 do
      begin
        filePath := fileList[imageIndex]
        //Please note that mImageList is an array of FMX.Objects.TImage 
        //which was filled when the Form is created (I create 300 TImage 
        //at Form create and later i load the images to the bitmap when 
        //the user clicks on a new directory(Chapter)

        mImageList[imageIndex].beginUpdate();
        try
          mImageList[imageIndex].loadFromFile(filePath);
          mImageList[imageIndex].tagString := filePath;
          mImageList[imageIndex].Scale := mImageScale;
          mImageList[imageIndex].Visible := false;
        except
          mImageList[imageIndex].EmptyBitmaps;
        end;
        mImageList[imageIndex].endUpdate();
      end;

      TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
        var
          I: Integer;
        begin
          for I := Low(mImageList) to High(mImageList) do
          begin
            mImageList[I].Visible := true;
          end;
  end);
end).Start;
```

I expect that when i scroll down through the images loaded on the form, i can see them all and they all get drawn on the form properly.

Comment: What is `mImageList`?

Comment: Looks awfully like you access UI controls outside the UI thread

Comment: @TomBrunberg `mImageList` is `Array of FMX.Objects.TImage`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't quite understand what you are trying to say, but in the `Form` i create an Object which in its constructor creates 300 `TImage` and after that each time the user clicks on a directory (Chapter) i load the images from that directory inside these 300 image, and i do this the way i shown at the top.

Comment: @aliahmadi, accessing UI controls in a thread <> UI thread, is not safe.

Comment: It means TImage is not thread safe. It is not meant to be accessed from background thread. Delphi 10,2 Tokyo introduced multithreading support for [TBitmap, TCanvas, and TContext3D](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Multi-Threading_for_TBitmap,_TCanvas,_and_TContext3D) so if you use that version or newer you can load your images in TBitmap inside background thread and then assign that bitmaps to TImage controls in UI thread.

Comment: I understand what all of you are saying, but i thought that by doing synchronize its like i am overcoming this issue? it seems i was wrong, just to clarify, you are saying, i have to 1- load all the images into bitmaps in `Multi thread` 2- i have to assign the bitmaps to TImage in `UI thread` , just one issue, how can i go from the `AnonymousThread` to `UI Thread` ? is calling a `procedure onBitmapLoadingFinished()` inside a `Synchronize Thread` the correct way ?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes i am using `10.2.3`, Just one very important question, is `TBitmapSurface` also Thread safe ?, because i actually use the its help to load my images (the images are very big so i load them in `TBitmapSurface` and then i cut it in half and draw it in two other `TBitmap` !)

Comment: Look again at you code. The code in `Synchronize` executes in the UI thread. Look at the code in the anon thread that is not inside the `Synchronize` call.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So if the Assignment of `TBitmap` to `TImage.bitmap` happens in the `Synchronize` everything will work as it should ?

Comment: TBitmapSurface should be thread safe. It is not UI component, and there is nothing inside it that would suggest it cannot be used in thread safe manner.

Comment: `TImage` is a UI control, which means you cannot access it in a thread other than the main thread. *Cannot access* means that code that is not executing in the main thread cannot touch the TImage at all, period. It does not mean *while displaying*, it means *cannot touch in any way*.